# Hatcher example 3H.3. Local coefficients via Modules

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm trying to understand the following example made by Hatcher at page 329 in the section "Local Coefficients via Modules"

[image: example]

The problem arises when I start to prove that a basis for $C_n^+(X')$ is given by the chains $\sigma + \tau (\sigma)$ where $\tau$ is the non-trivial deck transformation. Now I don't know how to prove that it is a generating set. Take a $\tau$-invariant simplex $\alpha$. I want to write $\alpha = c + \tau(c)$ for some chain $c$. I don't know where to start, because from what I know there could be only $\alpha$ as a simplex.

I almost sure there is some kind of trick here. 
I'd prefer hints rather than solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: There are no $\tau$-invariant simplices, because $\tau$ acts freely on $X'$.  To show that a general $\tau$-invariant chain $\sum a_i\sigma_i$ can be written in the form $c+\tau(c)$, try grouping the $\sigma_i$ into their orbits under the action of $\tau$.

Comment: this might be a good start! Let me think over it for a moment! :) Completely forgotten about the fact that the action is free :(